# How to cache a _Layout.cshtml containing a image-slider

Tags: html, caching, layout, razor, jssor

I have a _Layout.cshtml which contains a image-slider, which works perfectly fine. Problem here is that everytime I load another of my pages the _Layout file gets loaded as well and the slider starts with picture #1 from the image-container.

So my question is, if there´s a possibility to cache the _Layout file and to keep the slider on the current displaying image, even if I change to another page.

I´m totally new to html so I don´t any clue about caching at the moment. Would be glad for any help.

Best regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that images in your slider flipping by javascript and you can't cache that state.

Possible solution is to modify your slider so it will record last picture number (you can acheive that by subscribing to `$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE` [event](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-api.html)) to [localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) (or cookie and etc.) and then when you initialize your slider you need to read that last picture number and start your slider from that picture (you can pass [options](http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-options.html) with `$StartIndex`).